# MongoDB Export large number of docs into CSV or JSON String eficently

Tags: json, mongodb, csv, export

I am trying to export large number of docs (300K+)  with average size 20K into CSV or JSON.

Mongoexport takes > 20min for CSV and >10m for JSON.
Using Javascript printjson()  much worse.

PyMongo gets to about 5 min

Any other suggestions?

Comment: you have found any solution for this ...plz update

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way of exporting to CSV is `mongoexport` and I highly doubt that there will be a faster way. Also you have to understand that you are reading 6GB of data, and then writing 6GB of data on the disk. So I would not expect this to happen in a moment.

The behavior of printjson will be much slower, because you need to output all this text on the screen.

The question is why are you doing this? If you want to copy the data from one DB to another, there is [db.copyDatabase()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/), if you want to create a backup, [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) / mongorestore is better.

**P.S.** mongo is schemaless, so you need to specify what field you want when you export to csv, and I assume this adds this extra time in comparison to converting to JSON.